# Why does my image keep re-positioning in my AnchorPane on a drag and drop?

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop

You can see the behavior [here](https://www.useloom.com/share/93e0b2ae879048c59c38fa345f9807fa). I have tried a few different techniques, but I can't seem to get it right. The image will drag and drop perfectly the first time. After that, it will re-position at the origin point before it gets dragged again.

```
@FXML
private ImageView imageId;

@FXML
private AnchorPane imagePane;

private double startX;
private double startY;

@FXML
private void loadImage(){
    double width = imagePane.getWidth();
    double height = imagePane.getHeight();
    Image image = new Image("main/buttercup2.jpg");
    imageId.setImage(image);
    imageId.setX(width/10);
    imageId.setY(height/10);
}

@FXML
private void closeImage(){
    imageId.setImage(null);
}


// ****below is the part where I am having trouble****

@FXML
private void initialize(){
    imageId.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        startX = e.getSceneX();
        startY = e.getSceneY();
    });

    imageId.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
        imageId.setTranslateX(e.getSceneX() - startX);
        imageId.setTranslateY(e.getSceneY() - startY);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't include the initial `translateX` and `translateY` in your calculations. This way small movements reset the translation to values close to 0. Including the initial values in the calcualtion should fix this issue:

```
imageId.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
    startX = e.getSceneX() - imageId.getTranslateX();
    startY = e.getSceneY() - imageId.getTranslateY();
});
```